# What is the purpose of the '#' in Javadocs '{@link #method}'?

Tags: java, javadoc

What is the purpose of the hash `#` in the Javadoc link tag?

```
/** Call {@link #method} to do foo. */
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) uses `#` as a *separator* between class and method/constructor signatures or field names to avoid ambiguous links.

The Javadoc `@link` and `@see` tags can be used with references to packages, classes and specific methods/constructors or fields within a class. It is perhaps not obvious, but it is legal to have e.g. a class "c" in the package "a.b" and a class "b" in the package "a" with a field called "c" in the same project.

A Javadoc link to "package a.b, class c" would be written as `a.b.c`, whereas a link to "package a, class b, field c" would be written as `a.b#c`. If the name is distinct, the Javadoc tool will also accept the `.` separator before methods, constructors or fields.

If a link starts with `#`, it refers to a method/field/constructor in the same class. This is analogue to the anchor usage in HTTP URLs, where `href="doc.html#a1"` refers to the "a1" anchor in "doc.html" and `href="#a1"` refers to the "a1" anchor in the same document.

Answer (score 7):

It is a "separator" between class and method.

For example, you can include references to methods in the same class:

```
{@link #methodA() whatever}
```

Or references to methods that are in other classes, then the syntax is class # method, i.e.

```
{@link MyClass#methodA() whatever}
```

Then `#` is the separator.

Answer (score 2):

From [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags):

> Inserts an in-line link with visible text label that points to the
>   documentation for the specified package, class or member name of a
>   referenced class. This tag is valid in all doc comments: overview,
>   package, class, interface, constructor, method and field, including
>   the text portion of any tag (such as @return, @param and @deprecated).

Comment: IMO Even the initial answer was worth the +1. (I voted first )

Answer (score 0):

It inserts a link to the javadoc of another method in the same class.

For example, in the [String.isEmpty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) javadoc, there is a link to the [String.length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method.

The javadoc is :

```
Returns <tt>true</tt> if, and only if, {@link #length()} is <tt>0</tt>.
```

Comment: so # is a placeholder for package.class?

Comment: No, a placeholder which means 'this' class.

Comment: @obourgain: Not really. The empty string *before* the # is a placeholder meaning "this class".